# Plot and calculate the expression with error function in R

Tags: r, function

Hi all I have the function/expression with the complementary error function. I want to find the solution for different values of x. Complementary error function can be written as

```
erfc(x)=1-erf(x)
```

The expression I have is

```
erfc(\frac{x-Ut}{\sqrt{4Dt}})
```

I have written the expression in Latex syntax. How, you will understand it.
U and D are constants in the above expression. Now, I will assign the values of x using the following code:

```
x <- seq(from=0,by=0.5,length=500)
```

Now I want to define the expression above on a function so that I have values for different values of x.

A simple example of what I want is demonstrated by the following example.

```
x <- seq(from=0,by=0.5,length=500) 
y <- function(x){
  x^2+2*x+1
}
z = y(x) 
plot(x,z)
```

The thing that will be different in the example above and what I want is the definition of the function. How can I use the expression with error function on the function ? Is there any special package that handles error function ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, you want to parse a latex syntax to compute the erfc value for your x, is that the problem?

Comment: I basically want to use that expression in a function and compute value for x. You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error function is handled by base R, since it can be defined in terms of the CDF of the Normal distribution; See the examples at:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Normal.html

All you have to do is define the following function:

```
f <- function(x) 2-2*pnorm(sqrt(2)*(x-Ut)/sqrt(4*Dt))
```

since `erf(y) = 2*pnorm(sqrt(2)*y)-1`.

And then plot it using

```
z = y(x) 
plot(x,z)
```

Or, alternatively, using

```
plot(f, from=0, to=250)
```

Comment: Note that `pnorm(x) = 1-pnorm(x, lower=TRUE)`, so there is no contradiction between the definitions I used (`2-2*pnorm(...)`) and the one used in the documentation (`2*pnorm(...,lower=TRUE)`).

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know that error function does exist in R. Your example works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

As is pointed out [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/052937.html), the documentation for `pnorm()` says:

```
## if you want the so-called 'error function'
erf <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1
## (see Abramowitz and Stegun 29.2.29)
## and the so-called 'complementary error function'
erfc <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2), lower = FALSE)
```

Thus, you can use these definitions for `erf()` and `erfc()` in your function.